# How to add data from 2 different API into same table in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have 2 APIs. With the help of 1 API and map function, I appended the items in form of a table on UI but I want one more column in the same table that renders data from different APIs.I tried using a separate map function on another API and placing the variable in one  tag of the table but it rendered all items to the same cell. How can I add data from different APIs to the same column of the same table?

```
const App = () => {



const [data2, setData2] = useState([])
  const [app, setApp] = useState([])



const getData = async () => {
    try {
   let url = API1;
      let url2 = API2;

  const res = await fetch(url);
  const dataset = await res.json();

  const res2 = await fetch(url2);
  const dataset2 = await res2.json();

  setData2(dataset.data);
  setApp(dataset2.data)

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])


// trying to iterate over 2nd API key

  const addData = app.map((item)=>{
    return item.app_name
  })

  const DisplayData = data2.map(
    (item, index)=>{
        return(
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>{new Date(item.date).toDateString()}</td>
// want to create one more column in the same table that renders different data
                    <td>{addData}</td>
                    <td>{item.requests}</td>
                    <td>{item.responses}</td>
                    <td>{item.impressions}</td>
                </tr>
        )
    }
  )



  return (
  <>
  
      <div className="card w-50 mx-auto">
      <table className="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>S. no</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>App</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Requests</th>
        <th>Revenue</th>
        <th>Fill rate</th>
        <th>CTR</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {DisplayData}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
    </>


)
}
```

Comment: Does the data from API1 relate to the data from API2 in any way? In other words, should you be trying to merge the data in any way? Or you want a single table with all the API1 data in one column, *then* all the API2 data following in the other column? What should the expected result be?

Comment: data of API2 is a list of app names and a table already exists with data from API1. I want to render a separate column in that table with the name "Apps" that renders all the app names from API2. API1 and API2 are not related in any way.

Comment: Then what is the point of displaying them in the same table? If you *must* render them into the same table then render all of the API1 data into only the first X column(s) and then render all of the API2 data into only the second Y column(s). Is *this* the part you need help with? Can you provide sample data that you are rendering into the table?

Comment: API1 has various categories like revenue, impressions, and clicks that correspond to each table column and as well as to each app name from API2. That app name list has to be rendered as 1st column and then the later columns are of revenue, impressions, and clicks corresponding to that app name. They have no relation just have to display them. Hope I am clear in conveying it this time.

Comment: Can you provide example API data and an example expected output? The code doesn't quite match what you are asking for. The table looks to have 8 columns, but the `DisplayData` array has only 5 columns.

Comment: actually, that API is a little confidential. Can I please explain everything in your mail along with APIs and output data? It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: We are not asking for any proprietary/confidential/protected information, just dummy example data would be completely sufficient. You can even obfuscate the column names if you like. We just need a minimal, reproducible example for what you are trying to accomplish. The goal being to resolve it here and you can apply it your protected code.

Comment: so in total, I want 7 columns in my table namely date, app name, clicks, requests, revenue, fill rate, and CTR.Out of which, only the app name column needs to be rendered from API2, and the rest of the columns need to be rendered from API1.So I want to render the list of "app names" from API2 in the first column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try setData with the response of both API's which goes;

I've commented the part of code to be replaced.

```
const App = () => {



//const [data2, setData2] = useState([])
//const [app, setApp] = useState([])

const [data, setData] = useState([]);


const getData = async () => {
    try {
   let url = API1;
      let url2 = API2;
let response = [];
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const dataset = await res.json();

  const res2 = await fetch(url2);
  const dataset2 = await res2.json();

response.push(dataset.data);
response.push(dataset2.data);

  //setData2(dataset.data);
  //setApp(dataset2.data);

setData(data.flat(1));

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])


// trying to iterate over 2nd API key

  const addData = app.map((item)=>{
    return item.app_name
  })

  const DisplayData = data.map(
    (item, index)=>{
        return(
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>{new Date(item.date).toDateString()}</td>
// want to create one more column in the same table that renders different data
                    <td>{addData}</td>
                    <td>{item.requests}</td>
                    <td>{item.responses}</td>
                    <td>{item.impressions}</td>
<td>{{/* return all the data of 2nd api response}}</td>
                </tr>
        )
    }
  )

}
```

Comment: my data from API2 is shorter than API1 there a gap is getting created in table while iterating as items from API2 is missing

Answer (score 0):

You will need to render all columns for each set of data you are rendering. For one API's data you render an empty column element, and for the other all empty expect for the app name value.

Example:

```
<table className="table table-stripped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>App</th>
      <th>Clicks</th>
      <th>Requests</th>
      <th>Revenue</th>
      <th>Fill rate</th>
      <th>CTR</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {/* Render API1 data */}
    {data2.map((item) => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{new Date(item.date).toDateString()}</td>
        <td />
        <td>{addData}</td>
        <td>{ clicks data??? }</td>
        <td>{item.requests}</td>
        <td>{item.responses}</td>
        <td>{item.impressions}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
    {/* Render API2 data */}
    {app.map((item) => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td />
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td />
        <td />
        <td />
        <td />
        <td />
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```